# pipe symbol for "or"in Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use extensively MS Word's speech-to-text, but it frequently interprets my commas as "comment" or "common". I asked ChatGPT to write a reparative macro (see below), and it suggests to use: `.Text = "comment|common"`. I liked the idea of using the pipe symbol to provide a logical "OR", but it does not seem to work with MS Word. Is it ChatGPT's fault or Microsoft's fault? And anyway, is there a way to engineer Boolean logic into a VBA .Find statement?

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
With myRange.Find
    .Text = "comment|common"
    .Replacement.Text = ","
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
myRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it ChatGPT's fault? The answer to that question is always yes.

Comment: Word search / find doesn't support it. Option1: you can use RegExp (`pattern="comm(ent|on)"`) to replace it.  Option2: store two keywords in an array, replace it one by one.

Comment: Funny to think that Microsoft might be the one at fault for not supporting ChatGPT's ideas about how Word VBA might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You have it already, it's just a matter of turn it into a function. We may use a handler to call the replacements and define the array of words there

***Demo***:

[image]

**Code**

```
Sub Exec_ReplaceMishearings_Handler()
Const TxtMisHeardWords As String = "comment||common"
Const TxtReplaceMisHeardWords As String = ",||,"
Dim ArrTxtMisHeardWords() As String: ArrTxtMisHeardWords = Split(TxtMisHeardWords, "||")
Dim ArrTxtReplaceMisHeardWords() As String: ArrTxtReplaceMisHeardWords = Split(TxtReplaceMisHeardWords, "||")
Dim CounterArr As Long
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    For CounterArr = 0 To UBound(ArrTxtMisHeardWords)
    Call Exec_ReplaceMishearings(myRange, ArrTxtMisHeardWords(CounterArr), ArrTxtReplaceMisHeardWords(CounterArr))
    Next CounterArr
End Sub
Sub Exec_ReplaceMishearings(RangeToReplace As Range, TxtWordToFind As String, TxtWordToReplace As String)
    With RangeToReplace.Find ' 1. With RangeToReplace.Find
    .Text = TxtWordToFind
    .Replacement.Text = TxtWordToReplace
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With ' 1. With RangeToReplace.Find
    RangeToReplace.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

**Further thoughts**

Chat GPT ultimate goal was to do the array just failed to explain the logic, you may enhance your prompt and tell it that it failed to provide the logic for an array. You may read about an array [here](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/what-is-array). To add up, the code provided will not replace capitals, so I'd suggest you to give a read on the arguments for the replace.

Comment: Why construct an improper array and then correct it by using the `Split` function? Wouldn’t it be simpler, and better, to write the array correctly in the first place?

Comment: Usually is easier to deploy this way and easier to read afterwards, while I agree that we should dim at first `Dim Arr(1) as String` and then `Arr(0) = "Word1":Arr(1)="Word2"`, to avoid the usage of the "lazy" split approach: controlling everything on a string has been in my experience easier and does not impact performance

Comment: You don’t use the `Array` function? Much simpler for single dimension arrays.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I used to as well, but I found easier to just declare a constant: the rational behind it it's that sometimes some other users need to either change something or append something, and they are unlikely willing to change more than 2 or 3 lines to append for the array, so sometimes I have it on the sheet as a parameter with the same logic (a cell divided by ||) or a const at the top of the code as a const, depends a lot on the final business user will, need and attitude towards coding. IE they would re define comment=, and then common=.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [wildcards](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/using_wildcards.html) to match both words.

The search expression `<comm[eo][nt]{1,2}>` will match common and comment.

- `<` start of a word
- `comm` matches the beginning of the words comment and common
- `[eo]` matches one of either "e" or "o"
- `[nt]{1,2}` matches either "n", "t", "nt", "nn" or "tt". I couldn't think of a cleaner way to get both word endings.
- `>` end of a word

```vb
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
With myRange.Find
   .Text = "<comm[eo][nt]{1,2}>"
   .Replacement.Text = ","
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = True
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
myRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: If you're used to RegExp and wondering why I didnt do `<comm[eo]n[t]{0,1}>` it's because you cant search for zero of something in MS Word. At least not in the version that I have on my PC.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the reference links you provided, learned a lot.

Comment: This is a very good answer, I didn't know that you could use such complexity of wildcards directly in the find property